# Xamarin.Android Exception in Modifying ListView

Tags: android, visual-studio, listview, xamarin, xamarin.android

ListViews can be very useful in a lot of applications, but modifying them is a bit tricky for me. I am trying to create a custom listview with a button on each item in which when clicked, that specific item will be removed. I tried the code below but it always fires multiple times and it gives an Out of Range exception.

```
class DataAdapter : BaseAdapter
{
    private Activity activity;
    private List<DummyData> dataList;

    public DataAdapter(Activity activity, List<DummyData> dataList)
    {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.dataList = dataList;
    }


    public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return dataList[position].Id;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView ?? activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.DummyDataLayout, parent, false);

        TextView nameTextView = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.nameTextView);
        Button removeButton = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.removeButton);

        nameTextView.Text = dataList[position].Name;
        removeButton.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            dataList.Remove(dataList[position]);
            NotifyDataSetChanged();
        };

        return view;
    }

    //Fill in cound here, currently 0
    public override int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return dataList.Count;
        }
    }
}

class DataAdapterViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
{
    public TextView nameTextView { get; set; }
    public Button removeButton { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: Every time it get's the view, it rebinds the button to an event you need to clear the event before binding too it, that's where I would start.

Comment: Any suggestion on how it would be done?

Comment: You could in theory reinitialise the button before you bind to the event.  removeButton = new Button(this); then bind the click event.

Comment: I would use the arguments and get the item position to delete it and can you show the code in notify data set?